# Creating a new object from a file - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a ruby project where I have to read personal information in from a file and use that information to create a new object from a `Person` class that I created. The `personal_info.txt` file looks something like this:

```
John, Doe, 53, married
AZ, 01-01-1963
```

Usually I would do something like `john = Person.new("John", "Doe", 53, "married", "AZ", "01-01-1963")` to create the object, but I can't do that. I have to read the information from the file and use that information to create the object. I know how to read the file into my program, but I have no idea how to use that information as arguments for my new `Person` object. I'm not asking for anyone to complete this for me, I just need some advice. If you guys could give me some pointers, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess you're aware that you can almost always use variables and function calls in place of literal values? So, how far did you get with reading in the files? Does that result in one long string or does it result in a data structure with the individual values in individual fields? (I.e., do you _parse_ the read data or do you need help with that?) To see what's still missing it'd be good to show us the (maybe [boiled down](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) code of what you already got.

Comment: Are you in control of the structure of the file, or does this file come from another source?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a structured data format, like json, xml or csv. Then, use a parser to read data into the program.

Your data representation is pretty close to csv, apart from the fact that you're using two lines to represent an object.